# Pyspark Count Null Values Column Value Specific

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My input spark dataframe is;

```
  Date        Client  Current 
    2020-10-26  1       NULL   
    2020-10-27  1       NULL   
    2020-10-28  1       NULL   
    2020-10-29  1       NULL   
    2020-10-30  1       NULL   
    2020-10-31  1       NULL   
    2020-11-01  1       NULL   
    2020-11-02  1       NULL    
    2020-11-03  1       NULL    
    2020-11-04  1       NULL    
    2020-11-05  1       NULL    
    2020-11-06  1       NULL    
    2020-11-07  1       NULL    
    2020-11-08  1       NULL    
    2020-11-09  1       NULL    
    2020-10-26  2       NULL    
    2020-10-27  2       NULL    
    2020-10-28  2       NULL    
    2020-10-29  2       10      
    2020-10-30  2       23      
    2020-10-31  2       NULL    
    2020-11-01  2       NULL    
    2020-11-02  2       1       
    2020-11-03  2       NULL    
    2020-11-04  2       NULL    
    2020-11-05  2       3       
    2020-10-27  3       NULL    
    2020-10-28  3       NULL    
    2020-10-29  3       10      
    2020-10-30  3       NULL    
    2020-10-31  3       NULL    
    2020-11-01  3       NULL    
    2020-11-02  3       NULL    
    2020-11-03  3       32      
    2020-11-04  3       NULL    
    2020-11-05  3       3       
    2020-11-03  4       NULL    
    2020-11-04  4       NULL    
    2020-11-05  4       NULL
```

Dataframe is ordered by client_no and date. If the "Current column" is completely null for a client, the Full_NULL_Count column should write the null number in the first line of the client.  I shared the desired output according to the data above;

```
   Date        Client  Current Full_NULL_Count
    2020-10-26  1       NULL    15   -> All "Current" values are null for client 1. So first row 
                                        value is  equal to total null count for Client 1 .    
    2020-10-27  1       NULL    NULL
    2020-10-28  1       NULL    NULL
    2020-10-29  1       NULL    NULL
    2020-10-30  1       NULL    NULL
    2020-10-31  1       NULL    NULL
    2020-11-01  1       NULL    NULL
    2020-11-02  1       NULL    NULL
    2020-11-03  1       NULL    NULL
    2020-11-04  1       NULL    NULL
    2020-11-05  1       NULL    NULL
    2020-11-06  1       NULL    NULL
    2020-11-07  1       NULL    NULL
    2020-11-08  1       NULL    NULL
    2020-11-09  1       NULL    NULL
    2020-10-26  2       NULL    NULL ->There are non null current values for Client 2. So it' s null.
    2020-10-27  2       NULL    NULL
    2020-10-28  2       NULL    NULL
    2020-10-29  2       10      NULL
    2020-10-30  2       23      NULL
    2020-10-31  2       NULL    NULL
    2020-11-01  2       NULL    NULL
    2020-11-02  2       1       NULL
    2020-11-03  2       NULL    NULL
    2020-11-04  2       NULL    NULL
    2020-11-05  2       3       NULL
    2020-10-27  3       NULL    NULL ->There are non null current values for Client 3. So it' s null.
    2020-10-28  3       NULL    NULL
    2020-10-29  3       10      NULL
    2020-10-30  3       NULL    NULL
    2020-10-31  3       NULL    NULL
    2020-11-01  3       NULL    NULL
    2020-11-02  3       NULL    NULL
    2020-11-03  3       32      NULL
    2020-11-04  3       NULL    NULL
    2020-11-05  3       3       NULL
    2020-11-03  4       NULL    3    -> All "Current" values are null for client 4. So first row 
                                        value is  equal to total null count for Client 4.   
    2020-11-04  4       NULL    NULL
    2020-11-05  4       NULL    NULL
```

Could you please help me about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the number of nulls for a client and compare it with the number of rows for that client.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window
w = Window.partitionBy('Client')

result = df.withColumn(
    'Full_NULL_count',
    F.when(
        F.sum(F.col('Current').isNull().cast('int')).over(w) == F.count('*').over(w),
        F.count('*').over(w)
    )
).withColumn(
    'rn',
    F.row_number().over(w.orderBy('Date'))
).withColumn(
    'Full_NULL_count',
    F.when(
        F.col('rn') == 1,
        F.col('Full_NULL_count')
    )
).drop('rn').orderBy('Client', 'Date')

result.show(99)
+----------+------+-------+---------------+
|      Date|Client|Current|Full_NULL_count|
+----------+------+-------+---------------+
|2020-10-26|     1|   null|             15|
|2020-10-27|     1|   null|           null|
|2020-10-28|     1|   null|           null|
|2020-10-29|     1|   null|           null|
|2020-10-30|     1|   null|           null|
|2020-10-31|     1|   null|           null|
|2020-11-01|     1|   null|           null|
|2020-11-02|     1|   null|           null|
|2020-11-03|     1|   null|           null|
|2020-11-04|     1|   null|           null|
|2020-11-05|     1|   null|           null|
|2020-11-06|     1|   null|           null|
|2020-11-07|     1|   null|           null|
|2020-11-08|     1|   null|           null|
|2020-11-09|     1|   null|           null|
|2020-10-26|     2|   null|           null|
|2020-10-27|     2|   null|           null|
|2020-10-28|     2|   null|           null|
|2020-10-29|     2|     10|           null|
|2020-10-30|     2|     23|           null|
|2020-10-31|     2|   null|           null|
|2020-11-01|     2|   null|           null|
|2020-11-02|     2|      1|           null|
|2020-11-03|     2|   null|           null|
|2020-11-04|     2|   null|           null|
|2020-11-05|     2|      3|           null|
|2020-10-27|     3|   null|           null|
|2020-10-28|     3|   null|           null|
|2020-10-29|     3|     10|           null|
|2020-10-30|     3|   null|           null|
|2020-10-31|     3|   null|           null|
|2020-11-01|     3|   null|           null|
|2020-11-02|     3|   null|           null|
|2020-11-03|     3|     32|           null|
|2020-11-04|     3|   null|           null|
|2020-11-05|     3|      3|           null|
|2020-11-03|     4|   null|              3|
|2020-11-04|     4|   null|           null|
|2020-11-05|     4|   null|           null|
+----------+------+-------+---------------+
```

Comment: Hey @mck, sorry but it' s not working correctly. This function only writed the value 1 on the first line for each client. By the way, what is "w"?

Comment: @Salih, sorry I forgot to include the definition of w

Comment: Hey @mck, the function still only writed the value 1 to the "Full_NULL_count" on the first row for each client. So, it is not correct.

Comment: @Salih Oh yes sorry, it should be just w = Window.partitionby(...), without the order by.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in one line. Counting nulls per client, in case the count matches with number of records per client then you add that count, otherwise null

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy('Client')

df = df.withColumn("Full_NULL_Count", f.when(f.sum(f.when(f.col("Current").isNotNull(), 0).otherwise(1))
                                             .over(w) == f.count('*').over(w), 
                                             f.count('*').over(w)).otherwise(None))
df.show()
```